# HTML Function displaying as plain text

Tags: javascript, html, function, google-sheets

I have been working on this for quite some time, and have basically been teaching myself HTML, so I apologize if the code is sloppy or if this is a simple fix. Here is what I am attempting to do, and the problem I am running into:

Take Google Form responses, generate an email based on those responses and dynamically email a certain person in my organization based on the location response(this part is done and working, just adding for context). Then create a survey response that sends info back to the original responder, sent from the administrator that the form was sent to. This is the js that I have running, that is working when it is ran in the google project:

```
function getid() {

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/a/raytownschools.org/spreadsheets/d/1YWHu_yKn5bqq63x1A4e4-vBUtZANj-xjeF07IBpHP64/edit?usp=sharing');
         SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheets()[0]);
         var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
         var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();


}
```

When I attempt to run that in my HTML code, and insert it into the element, it is simply inserting that code as raw text. HTML isn't running the function, or returning the data that it should be (and does return when ran outside the HTML code as a js app).

I can post the full HTML code if that would be helpful. Hopefully someone on here can help me out.

Comment: There is no such thing as an HTML function.  That looks like JavaScript.

Comment: Are you calling `getid()`?  You can pull the text for the function all you want, but if you don't ever actually call the function, it'll never get executed.  Try adding `getid();` after the function declaration or wrap it in a self-calling anonymous function: `(function(){ ... })();` instead of a named function (the `function getid()` part)

Comment: Sorry I didn't add that I was already using the <script></script> for that function. A more appropriate title would have  been that JS wasn't executing a function within HTML. Thanks for the feedback on calling getid(), I'll see what I can figure out and post back.

Comment: Show us something where you are ***calling*** the `getid()` function.

Comment: Here is what I have running after the getid() function.

<script> window.onload = function() {
    var requestid = getid;
  document.getElementById("requestid").value =requestid;
  
};
  
  </script>

Essentially putting that function into an empty text field that I assigned the "requestid" element. However, as far as I can figure, the issue is less to do with how I am calling the function later on, and more to do w/ the fact that the function isn't doing what it should be. I started this project w/ no HTML or JS knowledge, so please bare with me, and thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

What you have there is a Javascript function. There aren't functions in HTML, HTML is a markup language.
You must add that function inside Javascript tags like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getid() {
        var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/a/raytownschools.org/spreadsheets/d/1YWHu_yKn5bqq63x1A4e4-vBUtZANj-xjeF07IBpHP64/edit?usp=sharing');
        SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheets()[0]);
        var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
        var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
    }

    alert( getid() );

</script>
```

Take a look at [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_script.asp), on how to use javascript.

**Edit**

Seems like that code you're trying to execute is for Google Apps Script. I think you must execute it inside the [Google script editor](https://script.google.com/), because they don't make this API available for regular websites. [Here](https://script.google.com/d/18B_57521EtP2AgTsYGHLc71rSPls3fjxy6fg83Jf_TxMcY0i05Ru02ST/edit?usp=sharing) is a running example with your code.

Comment: I've been in meetings since I posted this, sorry about the delay. I should have mentioned that I am using the script tags, and even put an alert at the end to see what it is outputting. When I use alert(getid); inside the script tags but after the function runs, it is outputting my function as if I had it in quotes, as raw text. It's driving me crazy.

Comment: @TonyBlanco : using `alert( getid )` is saying to _display the function named getid_ ... if you `alert( getid() )` then ***that*** is saying to _call_ the function named getid and display the result that the function returned.